# Passing parameter (directory) to %cd command in ipython notebook

Tags: python, directory, ipython, parameter-passing, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to pass a parameter (directory) to a %cd command in ipython notebook as below:

```
 rootdir = "D:\mydoc"
 %cd rootdir
```

but i get the following error:

```
 [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified: u'rootdir'
 D:\mydoc
```

when i'm doing

```
 %cd D:\mydoc
```

This obviously works but i want to be able to specify my working directories using parameters...

Many thanks who can help me.

Best Wishes

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `$` to use the value in a variable.

```
%cd $rootdir
```

Comment: [Error 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: u'D:\mydoc'
D:\mydoc

Comment: This error is different. I tried the same in my linux. It did work. You can try escaping the \. Try with a path like:  D:\\mydoc

Comment: thanks it works! i have to put double // . I'm using windows btw. Cheers